# Shortcode under a Shortcode Multiple times Possible?

Tags: plugins, functions, shortcode

```
[shortcode]
  [shortcode1 title="variable text"] Some text[/shortcode1]
  [shortcode1 title="variable text"] Some text[/shortcode1]
  [shortcode1 title="variable text"] Some text[/shortcode1]
  [shortcode1 title="variable text"] Some text[/shortcode1]
  [shortcode1 title="variable text"] Some text[/shortcode1]
  [shortcode1 title="variable text"] Some text[/shortcode1]
[/shortcode]
```

Based on the need for a shortcode an HTML parts needs to be repeated based on user/admin inputs. I have presented a format. Is the above a possibility?

Can a shortcode be published within a shortcode multiple times?

---

**Further explanation of the situation** Future reader may find it helpful→ This is the edifice of an HTML (**Hypothetical example**)

```
<div class="classone">
  <div class="classtwo">  
    <div class="classthree">
      <ul class="four"> 
        <li class="question">
          <h3>Question</h3>          
        </li> 
        <li class="answer">
          <p>Answer</p>          
        </li>            
      </ul>      
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

This part is repetitive and Inner shortcode →

```
<li class="question">
   <h3>Question</h3>          
</li> 
<li class="answer">
   <h3>Question</h3>         
</li>
```

I think the code for the external shortcode will be written like this →

```
function external_shortcode(){
  ob_start();
  ?>
  <div class="classone">
    <div class="classtwo">  
      <div class="classthree">
        <ul class="four"> 
          <!-- This is the place where I want the inner shortcode many time           -->
        </ul>      
      </div>  
    </div>  
  </div>
  <?php   
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'shortcode', 'external_shortcode' );
```

Code for the Inner shortcode →

```
function internal_shortcode($atts, $content = null){
  $data = [
     'title' => 'Some heading text goes here.',
  ];
  $values = shortcode_atts($data, $atts);
  ob_start();
  ?>
  <li class="question">
    <h3><?php  echo esc_attr($values['title']); ?></h3>          
  </li> 
  <li class="answer">
    <p><?php echo $content; ?></p>          
  </li>  
  <?php   
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'shortcode1', 'internal_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can include a shortcode however many times you like, inside a shortcode. Just make sure you set up the parent shortcode to parse shortcodes nested within.

So, for example, if your `[shortcode]` does something like

```
function outer_shortcode($content = null) {
    return '<div>' . $content . '</div>';
}
```

just be sure to update it to parse the content for other shortcodes:

```
function outer_shortcode($content = null) {
    return '<div>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
```

You can then nest however many duplicate shortcodes as you like inside.

Answer (score 1):

Using @WebElaine's example, all you need is to add the do_shortcode($content) to your current code:

```
// use both parameters in your function declaration, even if you will ignore the $atts
function external_shortcode($atts, $content){
  ob_start();
  ?>
  <div class="classone">
    <div class="classtwo">  
      <div class="classthree">
        <ul class="four">
           <?php
           // Using do_shortcode will cause Wordpress to output your inner shortcodes.
           do_shortcode($content);
           ?>
        </ul>      
      </div>  
    </div>  
  </div>
  <?php   
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'shortcode', 'external_shortcode' );
```