# Two different inner shortcode under shortcodes or multiple nesting of inner shortcodes

Tags: shortcode, css, html, content

```
<div class="eternal">
  <div class="one">
    [shortcode]Some text 1[/shortcode]    
    [shortcode]Some text 2[/shortcode]    
    [shortcode]Some text 3[/shortcode]    
    [shortcode]Some text 4[/shortcode]    
  </div>  
  <div class="two">
    [shortcodeanother]Some text 1[/shortcodeanother]    
    [shortcodeanother]Some text 2[/shortcodeanother]    
    [shortcodeanother]Some text 3[/shortcodeanother]    
    [shortcodeanother]Some text 4[/shortcodeanother]     
  </div>
</div>
```

I have asked a similar question before, which was also answered:
[Shortcode under a Shortcode Multiple times Possible?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/348408/shortcode-under-a-shortcode-multiple-times-possible)

But I am in a situation where I need to publish two inner shortcodes with different HTML.

In the answer suggested in the linked text when we intend to publish two inner shortcodes how can we do that when this is not unique in two cases:

```
return '<div>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
```

In the current situation outer shortcode is easy to create, but how can we do that with two inner shortcodes?

Or maybe if nesting of shortcodes is possible?

```
[shortcode]
  [shortcodenest1]
    [shortcodenest2]
    [/shortcodenest2]
  [/shortcodenest1]
[/shortcode]
```

Comment: What exactly is you problem with nested shortcodes? Do whatever nesting you want, just call do_shortcode() on inner content in your shortcode functions.

Comment: Sure, I will update you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can keep nesting shortcodes. Just keep using the `do_shortcode()` until the deepest level is reached. https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes

So you can do this,

```
[container]
  [other_column class="extra-class"]
    [content]
      col 1
    [/content]
    [another]
      col 1-2
    [/another]
  [/other_column]
  [column]
    [another]
      col 2
    [/another]
  [/column]
[/container]
```

To achieve output like this,

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="other-column extra-class">
    <div class="content">
      col 1
    </div>
    <div class="another">
      col 1-2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="another">
      col 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Provided you have shortcode functions something like this. I threw in an attributes example, should you need them.

```
function container_shortcode($atts = array(), $content = null) {
  return '<div class="container">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'container', 'container_shortcode' );

function column_shortcode($atts = array(), $content = null) {
  return '<div class="column">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'column', 'column_shortcode' );

function other_column_shortcode($atts = array(), $content = null) {
  $defaults = array(
    'class' => '',
  );
  $atts = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts, 'other_column_shortcode' );
  $class = (! empty($atts['class']) ) ? 'other-column ' . $atts['class'] : 'other-column';
  return '<div class="' . esc_attr($class) . '">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'other_column', 'other_column_shortcode' );

function content_shortcode($atts = array(), $content=null) {
  return '<div class="content">' . $content . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'content', 'content_shortcode' );

function another_shortcode($atts = array(), $content=null) {
  return '<div class="another">' . $content . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'another', 'another_shortcode' );
```